# Fast changing labels in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to display some numbers, as fast as possible in Tkinter. The Program, I am trying to do, gets many numbers send and should show those.

Here is an similar environment, where tinter has to change a label very quickly.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
window = Tk()
lbl13 = Label(window, text="-")
lbl13.grid(column=0, row=0)

x = 0
while 1:
   lbl13.config(text = str(x))
time.sleep(2)
x +=1

window.mainloop()
```

The Tkinter window doesn't even open on my computer. Is that because i have too weak hardware? What could I change that this Program also runs on my Computer. Thank you for every answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite while loop will keep the program from getting to the line where you call `window.mainloop()`. You should call window.update() repeatedly instead of window.mainloop() at the end:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
window = Tk()
lbl13 = Label(window, text="-")
lbl13.grid(column=0, row=0)

x = 0
while 1:
   lbl13.config(text = str(x))
   window.update()
   x +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `after` and a proper `mainloop` is probably a more more flexible way to achieve what you want; it is also reusable in different contexts, and can be used in an application that does more than trivially increment a number on a label:

maybe something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def increment():
        var.set(var.get() + 1)
        label.after(1, increment)

    window = tk.Tk()
    var = tk.IntVar(0)
    label = tk.Label(window, textvariable=var)
    label.pack()

    increment()

    window.mainloop()
```